# Access url through another url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iframe

I'm developing a web page using asp .net and have another application which is published in my host. I want to access to the application just from my page and the application is not accessible from other IPs.
I used iframe, but iframe is connecting client directly to the application which is not what I want. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I think without some wierd code, this is not possible since the IFrame is client side calls. This will make a hard time for you to bypass.

A little side question is, why dont you want people to access you page directly on the domain / ip, when showing it in the iframe will still let people access the page?

Comment: because of security issues, I cant give access to the application server and users can only access through this page.

Comment: Then you could attack this problem with making your own kind of IFrame where it is the server that makes the calls and prints it into div's.

Comment: Can you explain more, or if there is any sample?
The application is distributed and I want my page to connect to the url through wan and shows the result on wan and internet.

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to navigate the page in the iframe?

Comment: yes, there is an interactive page which changes the contents and the application is from another company